# Windows successfully boots after power outage being in sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, memory, sleep, hibernate

So, something weird is happening here. The scenario is as follows:

- I put the computer to sleep
- A power outage occurs
- Power gets back
- I start the computer
- It boots normally as if power never went out (`Resuming Windows` shows up)
- At first it is a bit laggy but then it becomes perfect

Umm, I don't know what's going on here. I have had this happen many times in the past years. I have searched a bit, but found no answers.

I know the following:

- RAM needs power to keep the data within
- Sleeping basically keeps power to memory so that when you startup again, Windows resumes using what is already stored in the memory
- Hibernating on the other hand stores the memory on harddisk (hiberfil file), and then restores it back into Ram when PC starts again
- Hibernating is similar to shutting down the PC from a power standpoint. The power is cut from the whole board until the PC is used again

My hardware configuration is about 10+ years old:

- AMD Phenom 9850
- 6 GB (3x2GB) HyperX Kingston DDR2
- GA-MA790X-DS4 Motherboard

---

- **Why is this happening?**
- **Can it be something specific to my hardware configuration?**

Comment: You are probably hibernating (which comes back on when you press the power button). If sleeping (plain sleep, not hybrid, not hibernating, just sleep) then I find it stays sleeping. You might try updating your BIOS and Power Drivers.

Comment: @John Well, I am not hibernating 100%. I don't even have the option available on the submenu next to shutdown.

Comment: @John What is hybrid though?

Comment: Hybrid is half way between normal sleep and hibernate. So called deep sleep. I turn most modes off except normal sleep as I find that works best on my computers.

Comment: @John Well, I have just checked and yeah that's the issue. I have been using hybrid sleep all of those years. I never heard of it until now. Guess you can add that as an answer. In power options it is the "allow hybrid sleep" setting.

Comment: I did post an answer for you. Hopefully you will find it helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be hibernating (which comes back on when you press the power button) if this function is available to you.

If sleeping (plain sleep, not hybrid, not hibernating, just sleep) then I find it stays sleeping. You might try updating your BIOS and Power Drivers.

If you have Hybrid Sleep (half way between normal sleep and hibernate; so called deep sleep), turn that off and maintain just regular sleep.

I turn most modes off except normal sleep as I find that works best on my computers

Answer (score 1):

Check your BIOS settings and see if there is a power option. If not then you might be on hibernating.